# event prevent default not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

This is a kind of similar duplicate to some others here, but I think I'm using event.preventDefault() correctly in this case.

this my html :

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Setuju dan kirim" onclick="check_empty_2()">
```

in Chrome, it is work. but in Firefox, it does not work.

this my code :

```
function check_empty_2() {

if (document.getElementById('reg_nama').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_email').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_no').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_rumah').value == "" ) {
    alert("Harap isi semua bidang !");
} else {
    document.getElementById('reg_rfid').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('alert_rfid').style.display = "block";
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#alert").offset().top - 150
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}

}
```

please correct my code, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you need to read and pass event as argument like

```
<input onclick="check_empty_2(event)" ...
```

and

```
function check_empty_2(event) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's work to me.
i am beginner for this case. and i has read other forum for this case. but its does not work to..

Answer (score 0):

For firefox to work change it to

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Setuju dan kirim" onclick="check_empty_2(event)">
```

And the function to

```
function check_empty_2(event) {....
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's work to me. i am beginner for this case. and i has read other forum for this case. but its does not work to..

Answer (score 0):

You Forgot to pass Event,From Current Scenario  You will Get error **Event is undefine** in Firebug

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Setuju dan kirim" onclick="check_empty_2(event)">

function check_empty_2(event) {
...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's work to me. i am beginner for this case. and i has read other forum for this case. but its does not work to..

Comment: Your welcome @Afrgun...!!Welcome to World of CODING..!!

Answer (score 0):

First a fall. You have written code wrong. event.preventDefault(); should not inside of else.
It should be:

```
function check_empty_2(event) {

if (document.getElementById('reg_nama').value == "" ||     document.getElementById('reg_email').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_no').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_rumah').value == "" ) {
 alert("Harap isi semua bidang !");
} else {
document.getElementById('reg_rfid').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('alert_rfid').style.display = "block";
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#alert").offset().top - 150
});

}
event.preventDefault();
}
```

On more way to do:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Setuju dan kirim">

$(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(event){ 
  if (document.getElementById('reg_nama').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_email').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_no').value == "" || document.getElementById('reg_rumah').value == "" ) {
   alert("Harap isi semua bidang !");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('reg_rfid').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('alert_rfid').style.display = "block";
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#alert").offset().top - 150
    });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```